# Custom Exception as checked Exception

Tags: java, exception

In Java, if we create custom exception by extending Exception class then it will be considered as checked exception. By definition, checked exception are forced by the compiler like if we are writing below code then we are bound to catch FileNotFoundException

```
try{
  fis = new FileInputStream("abc.txt");

}

catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
  System.out.println("The source file does not exist. " + e);
}
```

In order to invoke custom exception, I need to explicitly throw it. So how this is checked then? It should be unchecked as compiler is not forcing me anything.

Regards
Shaikh

Comment: I can not understand nothing in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checked/unchecked refers to the requirement of handling the exception by the code that uses your method throwing exception.

Say You throw an unchecked exception in your method (RuntimeException or its subclass). You do not have to signal that your method throws it and anyone that uses your code does not need to explicitly handle it.

However if You throw checked exception (Exception that isn't subclass of RuntimeException) then your method must explicitly say that it throws exception and anyone that uses your code must handle that exception - either by also declaring their method as method that throws an exception (rethrow) or by using a try-catch block, around invocation of your method that throws checked exception.

Comment: is there any constraint on compiler has to force for checked exception ?

Comment: Yes. It won't compile code that uses method throwing checked exception and not handling it.